# sharing sessions between Rails 3.1 applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-state

I have 2 Rails applications (separated but sharing same top level domain). In development, I run the first application under localhost:3000 and the other one under localhost:3500

These two applications have the same users (not really but let's keep it simple).

So, when a user logs into application 1, I want him to be able to go to application 2 without having to sign-in again.

To do this, I changed the initializer, session_store.rb to:

```
Iview::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_iview_session', :domain => :all
```

I hoped this would be enough as, in my understanding, when accessing app. 2, the app. would be looking for the cookie of app 1 and assume the user is logged-in but it doesn't do the trick (at least in development).

What do I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the `secret_token.rb` initializer to the same key?